# The undefined name in the loop?

Tags: pylint

I was misleded by Pymodelint and asked an embarrassing quesiton today [here](https://github.com/ruotianluo/self-critical.pytorch/issues/1).
TL;DR:

```
def test():                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    a = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    for i in range(5):                                                                                                                                                                                          
        if i == 2:                                                                                                                                                                                              
            a = b  # an alert appears here saying that [Pymode] E0602 undefined name 'b' [pyflakes]                                                                                                                                                                               
        b = a + 1                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        print(b)
```

The pymodelint is compilted for python3. I have tested the above code to reproduce the error alert.

Why there should be an alert?

Comment: Pylint doesn't run your code. It can't know that the if statement is false during the first iteration.

Comment: Then should I initiate b ahead to prevent such alerts appearing? Or any other methods to avoid it?